# mySQL regex_replace remove all beginning numbers from mixed input

Tags: mysql, regex, regex-replace

I need a regex pattern to remove all numeric input from the beginning of a field that stops at the first alphabetic character and leaves any remaining numbers that follow alphabetic characters.

Here is the simplest test case.

```
CREATE TABLE tempdemo (tdfields varchar(10));
INSERT INTO tempdemo (tdfields) VALUES ('1'), ('11'), ('111'), ('a'), ('ab'), ('abc'), ('1a'), ('a1');

SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(tdfields, '^[0-9]*$', '') FROM tempdemo;
```

From the code, I would like the following output: :blank:, :blank:, :blank:, a, ab, abc, a, a1

Right now, the regex pattern leaves '1a' instead of 'a' which is undesireable.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: replace `\d*([^\d].*)` with `$1`

Comment: Simply remove EOL anchor: `SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(tdfields, '^[0-9]*', '') FROM tempdemo;`. Now the pattern tells to find the digits group from the value beginning till the first non-digit (this can be EOL, letteror any other char) and remove this group. Ungreedy flag is not specified, so all digits until non-digit matches.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```sql
CREATE TABLE tempdemo (tdfields varchar(10));
INSERT INTO tempdemo (tdfields) VALUES ('1'), ('11'), ('111'), ('a'), ('ab'), ('abc'), ('1a'), ('a1');

SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(tdfields, '^[0-9]+', '') FROM tempdemo;
```

It will remove *one or more digits from the start of the string*.

**More details**:

- `^` - start of string
- `[0-9]+` - one or more digits.

`$` matches the start of string position.

Note that `^[0-9]*` is not a good pattern here since it matches any string, and `+` variation will only match when necessary, when there are digits at the start of the string.